# check combobox selected index changed in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi all I'm developing an accounting software for a small business where I'm facing an issue in invoice part where user is going to put item for buy / create invoice here I'm fetching data from items table to display as a combobox in data grid view but I want to fetch amount and item code when user will select a item in combo box also I want to hide the selected item from the next row so user is not able to select same item again and again. I had tried all possible solution available on internet mostly are for normal combobox or else in the c# which i'm not able to understand.

[image: Image of invoice page]

Comment: If you remove the item from the previous selected combobox, the system will give u an error due to the item you select earlier is not found in the combobox  item column. You can either use different method like prompt out a selection list on click to select the item or validate the item is selected on the DataGridViiew_EndEdit Action

Comment: okk understood can you please help me into the first question like how to triggger when combobox selected index change in datagrid view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it under the CellEndEdit Event

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit

        Dim StockCol As Integer = dgv.Columns("StockColName").Index  ' Get the combobox column index



        Try

             For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1

            If e.RowIndex <> i Then     'skip the comparison for current row
                If dgv.Item(StockCol , i).Value = dgvPurchase.Item(StockCol , e.RowIndex).Value Then
                    MsgBox("Similar Item is selected", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                    dgv.Item(StockCol , e.RowIndex).Value = ""  'reset the cell to ""
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            End If
        Next
        Catch
        End Try
```

Comment: okay please can you help me for first question of how to call a function for fetching data on seelcted index change like if user select some item i will call a query to fetch other details for that item.

Comment: you need create another form and push a data to that form and exclude those user has entered. Quite a lot of coding.

Comment: No no no I just want to know the value of cell item name when it's selected like we do in normal combobox with SelectedIndexChanged is there something which can be use full to get value of that and I can run another fuction on that trigger.

Comment: under dgv user Cell_End_Edit like the example I show u